# Add attribute to all CSS rules except some

Tags: css

I need to add an attribute `[dir=ltr]` to all the rules of a big CSS file except for some ones.

Source CSS:

```css
.rule-1 {
  color:black
}
.rule-2 {
  color: yellow
}
.rule-3 { /* exclude */
  color: blue
}
.rule-4 {
  color: red
}
```

Target CSS:

```css
[dir=ltr] .rule-1 {
  color:black
}
[dir=ltr] .rule-2 {
  color: yellow
}
.rule-3 {
  color: blue
}
[dir=ltr] .rule-4 {
  color: red
}
```

Maybe a CSS postprocessor is needed here.

Comment: Please clarify more

Comment: By what criteria do you need to achieve that?

Comment: Manually excluded rules should not get the `dir` attribute

Comment: read about `:not()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css :not() attribute, example below:

```
[dir=ltr]:not(.rule-3) {
    //..
}
```

You can learn more about this attribute and what it does [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not#:%7E:text=The%20%3Anot()%20CSS%20pseudo,as%20the%20negation%20pseudo%2Dclass.)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved using the PostCSS plugin `postcss-prefix-selector`.

**`postcss.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        "postcss-prefix-selector": {
            prefix: '[dir=ltr]', exclude: [/.rule-3(?![\w])/]
        }
    }
}
```